# When does a proposal fail (before beta)?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Currently, there are a number of proposals which seem to struggle to get into beta but which could also be subsumed in the emerging Computer Science proposal (see [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3074/should-we-merge-the-various-computer-science-proposals)). I was asking myself: when is it appropriate to suggest a merge?

More to the point, the question is: When should we consider an unclosed, not yet in beta proposal failed? As far as I am aware there is no rule/process for this.

One thing I can think of is to investigate the graph of followers/commiters over time. If it shows (significant) characteristics of saturation (i.e. convergence), start a process that checks wether the proposal is still necessary, suggests merges with other proposals (that might have created and even launched while the failed proposal was in either phase) or close it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that suggesting a merge quite early makes people aware there is an alternative. This can lead to early discussion before that saturation point happens, and a plan can be developed to merge at the right time. This discussion may also throw up different possibilities for a merge.

If you leave it late, committers may have started to trail away before merge discussions commence, so they may not be aware of the merge, or may have given up entirely.

Comment: You have a point there. However, if you do it early you will be opposed heavily by people that feel strongly about the not-yet-struggling proposal.